# React Native fetch wait for dynamic content

Tags: reactjs, react-native, web-scraping, fetch, domparser

I have a React Native app that uses the `dom-parser` module to extract relevant pieces of information from a website, which is not owned by me. The information that I need is loaded dynamically in the page after it finishes loading in the browser. Is there a way to get this in a react native app using `fetch()`? I don't want the users to see the website open up in the app.

What I've tried:

```
    const html = (await (await fetch(this.search_url)).text()); //get the document
    var dom = parser.parseFromString(html); //parse it
    var json = dom.getElementsByTagName("script")[5].innerHTML //this is the element that I need
    console.log(json)

    fetch(this.search_url).then((response)=>response.json()).then((json)=>{
        var dom = parser.parseFromString(html);
        var json = dom.getElementsByTagName("script")[5].innerHTML
        console.log(json)
    })
```

Both of these return a blank response as output. However, when I looked up the source of `this.search_url` in a browser, it is loading the data after a few seconds of loading the page. Is there a way to get this data in the app? Maybe some trick to make `fetch()` wait for a few seconds before writing the response?

Comment: you can check if `this.search_query` is exist or contains some specific words then do that all things

Comment: I'm sorry @NishargShah it ain't `this.search_query` in the question I typed it wrong. It's `this.search_url`. By this, I mean the URL to be fetched from. Hope this makes the question more clear.

Comment: same logic as I said

Comment: Well I'm assuming this is happening because the website is loading the data dynamically after loading in the browser. If so, it surely won't contain the necessary words. If so, how do I get it? Is there a way to timeout reading the response after sending the request using `fetch()`?

Comment: send the request using fetch and set some flag to false and after successful response set that flag to true and in render method check if that flag is true only then and then you need to render it

Comment: No, no I need it for sure  I can't render without that data. That's the whole point of this question.

Comment: I need a successful response for sure

Comment: you don't understand my words, toggle your flag from false to true and check-in render method if that flag is true then you need to render it. BTW I give you one knowledge, if you are changing the state then react automatically rerender your page, if you follow this you will solve your problem, Thanks !!.